# Unable to update Facebook event start time

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I have been trying to edit the start time of my event (hosted by a page with co-hosts) over the last few days and repeatedly finding that when I change the event with a new time, the time doesn't change. I've tried on both desktop and mobile without success.

I'm editing the event from a different time zone than where it is happening, which may be a factor. This morning I finally got this mysterious error message when editing the page: "Editing isn't currently supported for Keywords and Event Schedules."

I searched for this error message on Google and there's no obvious solution, so I'm posting it here as a place for posting information in case anyone has insights into what might be going on.

Answer (score 1):

I think I may have figured out this issue: on the desktop Facebook application, the time zone being used is not always clear. When I was editing the event, I was thinking that I needed to enter it in my current time zone, but because it was an event with a location in a physical place, I needed to enter the time in the time zone where it is happening. Then when I look at the event it is displayed in my current time zone. So once I adjusted my thinking to edit for the time zone where the event is happening, it worked.

The error message appears to have been unrelated.

Answer (score 1):

I changed the category and it allowed other changes.

Answer (score -1):

I have found this same error as well.  I had no issues with a time zone, I just needed to change the time of our event.  It's a no go. All I can find to resolve this is to actually delete and redo your event from scratch.  Not ideal.

Answer (score -1):

Still no aswer to this question? I need to change the line-up inside my event, but I still get this message. Is Facebook actually aware of this?